# org.openapitools en gradle no funciona

Tags: java-8, gradle, intellij-idea, build.gradle

En **Intellij IDEA** estoy probando este código. Cree un proyecto con Gradle, Java 1.8. Tengo el SDK correcto. Basicamente los imports de [org.openapitools](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/plugins/) no funcionan, y ya no se que dependencias poner porque probe muchísimas cosas pero ninguna anda.

El código de a continuación es de un SDK de communications de AVALARA. Lo que quiero es probar [esto](https://github.com/Avalara/Communications-Developer-Content/blob/master/afc_saaspro_tax/afc_rest_apis/SDK/java/README.md), pero no puedo hacerlo andar.

```
import org.openapitools.client.ApiClient;
import org.openapitools.client.ApiException;
import org.openapitools.client.Configuration;
import org.openapitools.client.auth.*;
import org.openapitools.client.models.*;
import org.openapitools.client.api.CustomizationApi;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApiClient defaultClient = Configuration.getDefaultApiClient();
        defaultClient.setBasePath("http://localhost");


        CustomizationApi apiInstance = new CustomizationApi(defaultClient);
        Integer requestedClientId = 56; // Integer | Client id associated with profile(s) to be fetched  Null value will use client id submitting the request or default client id as applicable.
        Integer requestedProfileId = 56; // Integer | Configuration profile id to be fetched  Use 0 to indicate all profiles  Null value will use profile id from request or 0 if not set.
        TaxCalculationSettingTypes itemType = new TaxCalculationSettingTypes(); // TaxCalculationSettingTypes | Item Type  Examples:    Configuration, Bundle, Exclusion, Override, All
        try {
            TaxCalculationSettingsResponse result = apiInstance.apiV2ProfilesGetProfilesGet(requestedClientId, requestedProfileId, itemType);
            System.out.println(result);
        } catch (ApiException e) {
            System.err.println("Exception when calling CustomizationApi#apiV2ProfilesGetProfilesGet");
            System.err.println("Status code: " + e.getCode());
            System.err.println("Reason: " + e.getResponseBody());
            System.err.println("Response headers: " + e.getResponseHeaders());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Pero no me reconoce ningun import. En `build.gradle` tengo esto:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.openapitools:openapi-generator-gradle-plugin:3.3.4"
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id "org.openapi.generator" version "4.3.1"
}
apply plugin: 'org.openapi.generator'
```

También probe esto en `build.gradle`y tampoco:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openapitools/openapi-generator
    compile group: 'org.openapitools', name: 'openapi-generator', version: '4.3.1'
}
```

UPDATE: Recien viendo la configuración de Intellij, me aparece que el `Gradle JVM` no reconoce al `JAVA_HOME`. No se si tiene que ver o no, porque en realidad tenia la opción de Project SDK. La cambie por las otras, que es la 1.8, y tampoco nada.[image]

Comment: No estoy muy familiarizado con este IDE, generalmente uso Eclipse, pero dado que es un error de `build path` entonces sugiero que descargues directamente la librería de maven y la importes a tu proyecto mientras tanto, o probar la importación del apartado de gradle, te dejo el enlace [org.openapitools](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openapitools/openapi-generator-maven-plugin/3.3.4)

Comment: Ahi probe y tampoco. No se por que, porque antes probe con otras cosas de MVN y me anduvieron. Gracias de todas formas @Diego-1743